# What is the best way to STM32G4 OPAMP as amplifier with BIAS line from DAC?

Tags: stm32

Small update - this question is about **switch/multiplexer** settings for internal OPAMP "pins"

I'm trying to amplify my input signals with internal OPAMPs on STM32G4 mcu, also i need to control bias because signals are shifted. Bias levels are adjusted with DAC.

As long as my mcu has only 3 DAC pin-outputs, but 5 of 6 OPAMPS have internal connection to DAC outputs, I try to pass bias level internally.

I was successful enough configuring OPAMP (in MXCube because I hope it will help to make all this a little bit portable) connected to both ADC and DAC internally as

```
 PGA_Connected-INVERTINGINPUT_IO0_BIAS-DAC_OUTPUT2-INP_Output_internal
```

This setting in CubeMX generates me this kind of pin connection in init function:

```
OPAMP_PGA_CONNECT_INVERTINGINPUT_IO0_BIAS
```

but also, i can raise signal manually changing that kind of connection to:

```
OPAMP_PGA_CONNECT_INVERTINGINPUT_IO0
```

This way I get more classical diff opamp

Can someone explain me:

- What is the difference in **BIAS** connection? Connection point is between resistor divider?
- Why CubeMX don't offer option for direct connection of inverting input? It is just a software limitation or there is also something related to hardware and this kind of manual change is bad practice?
- Maybe someone tried it already - is this sort of connection available on all internal OPAMPs or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of guessing what HAL library can or not simply read the documentation called Reference manual. https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00355726-stm32g4-series-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: ***`Maybe someone tried it already`*** you do not have to try - simply read the documentation. Opamp is a very simply peripheral

Comment: Opamp is simple, but question is about multiplexer in front of opamp. Documentation has zero info about what is "BIAS" input compared to direct input in multiplexer internal channel setting

Comment: Because there is no difference, the documentation is quiet

Comment: But signal (amplification level) is definitely different, also, DAC values to set BIAS differs ~ 4 times. I suppose that difference is connection point relative to resistor network, but unfortunately can't find any exact info